# Django custom user model meta overlaps when importing from another project

Tags: python, django

I'm remaking a script to sync data from an old python2 project to a new with python3. The way the last programmer made it work appears to be by importing both, the new and old models into a script in the old project using:

```
sys.path.append("route to the new project")
```

It works for importing every model except for a custom user model from the new project, when I try to work with it, like using UserProfile.objects.all() it crashes with:

```
relation "user_userprofile" does not exist
```

LINE 1: SELECT "user_userprofile"."id" FROM "user_userprofile"

The right table is user_models_userprofile, because the app containing the model is "user_models" instead of "user".

The app_label from the imported model shows "user", which is probably the default app_label when extending AbstractUser, it is probably ignoring the app_label attribute from my model and using the one from AbstractUser.

Any ideas of how to make it work? Also sorry for my english.

**EDIT**
UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    class meta:
        app_label = 'user_models'

    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='example@example.com')
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    tour_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

There is no 'User' model, its just that custom model.

I import the model using

```
sys.path.append('route to new project')
from user_models.models import UserProfile
```

Comment: You can tell Django which table to use for a model by specifying the `db_table` option in `Meta` options, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#db-table).

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that, the problem is that whatever I specify in Meta is overwritten by AbstractUser when I import the model. It works on it's own app, it fails when I import it in the old one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "import the model". You have to provide more details of what you're doing. The `sys.path.append...` makes no sense. Any model in django needs to be part of an app that you added to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I know, right? But is the way the code was when they gave it to me, and it works, the sys.path line let python import from another directory, in this case from another entire project.

Comment: I understand it can import from another folder outside of your project this way, but you still have to define your apps for the models to work. You have to show us more code of your new project. What's `INSTALLED_APPS`? And what's the `UserProfile` model and the `User` models. The app_label **does not come from AbstractUser** because it's part of the 'django.contrib.auth' app.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question with the model. Also I need to say that other models that I import the same way works perfectly, it's something with that custom model.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way to correct the app_label and db_table from the user and the companies relation.

First import the model, and then overwrite the _meta atributes.

```
from user_models.models import UserProfile

UserProfile._meta.db_table="user_models_userprofile"
UserProfile._meta.app_label="user_models"
UserProfile.companies.through._meta.db_table="user_models_userprofile_companies"
UserProfile.companies.through._meta.app_label="user_models"
```

Is not the prettier way to do it but it works.